# C# .net For() Step?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, loops, for-loop

I have a function, that processes a list of 6100 list items. The code used to work when the list was just 300 items. But instantly crashes with 6100. Is there a way I can loop through these 6100 items say 30 at a time and execute a new thread per item?

```
    for (var i = 0; i < ListProxies.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var s = ListProxies.Items[i] as string;
        var thread = new ParameterizedThreadStart(ProxyTest.IsAlive);
        var doIt = new Thread(thread) { Name = "CheckProxy# " + i };
        doIt.Start(s);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the record, spotting and naming what exactly crashes (the line) and the crash message help greatly in finding solutions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you *really* need to spawn a new thread for each work item? Unless there is a genuine need for this (if so, please tell us why), I would strongly recommend you use the [Managed Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx) instead. This will give you the concurrency benefits you require, but without the resource requirements (as well as the creation, destruction and *massive* context-switching costs) of running thousands of threads. If you are on .NET 4.0, you might also want to consider using the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).

For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ListProxies.Items.Count; i++)
{
   var s = ListProxies.Items[i] as string;
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProxyTest.IsAlive, s);       
}
```

On another note, I would seriously consider renaming the `IsAlive` method (which looks like a boolean property or method) since:

1. It clearly has a `void IsAlive(object)` signature.
2. It has observable side-effects (from your comment that it "increment a progress bar and add a 'working' proxy to a new list").

Comment: The ThreadPool would absolutely be the way to go here. Threads are expensive.

Comment: Agreed.  Unless these are long-running threads this would be a place for the thread-pool.  I guess you could also look and the parallel library and use parallel.for to spread the load across cores.

Comment: @Wayne Threads aren't really expensive... 6000 threads is just purely excessive though :-) (You are right about using something to sanely manage the number.)

Comment: If you're using the Task Parallel Library (really cool btw), be very careful of how you write your for loop. Speaking from experience it's very easy to spawn 500 threads at once that may or may not accidentally bring down a SVN server... just sayin'... So, yeah, make sure to place an upper bound on the number of threads that can be active if you use that library. That library gives lots of good info about the computer too, so you could use that info with an equation to determine your upper bound.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Task parallel library,  check out `Parallel.ForEach(Collection, Method);`

Comment: @Ani, IsAlive is a method. It does a fast ping of the ip/port for response. I need a method to handle all those. I need to test each proxy in the list.

Comment: @Dremation: 1. The method doesn't return anything? 2. Why the concurrency? 3. Do you need notification when each task / some / all tasks are complete? 4. Any real need to run each task on a separate thread?

Comment: IsAlive will increment a progress bar and add a "working" proxy to a new list.

Answer (score 3):

There is a limit on the number of threads you can spawn.  6100 threads does seem quite a bit excesive.

I agree win Ani, you should look into a ThreadPool or even a Producer / Consumer process depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

There are quite a few processes for handling multi threaded applications but without knowing what you are doing in the start there really is no way to recommend any approach other than a ThreadPool or Producer / Consumer process (Queues with SyncEvents).

At any rate you really should try to keep the number of threads to a minimum otherwise you run the risk of thread locks, spin locks, wait locks, dead locks, race conditions, who knows what, etc...

If you want good information on threading with C# check out the book [Concurrent Programming on Windows By Joe Duffy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X) it is really helpful.